# Main character is summoned to another world and saves female characters from lizard lord

Tags: story-identification, manga

Is a black and white manga and I read this a year or two ago: The main character is a mage I think and saves the one of the female characters from a lizard men tribe that was going to use her. He manipulated them cause the King has hella kids.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Is this a manga, a novel, or what?  When and where did you read/watch this?

Comment: Is a manga and. Read this like a while ago

Comment: Was this full colour or mostly black & white?

Comment: @Wil.L How long ago is a while ago? 6 months? 40 years? Knowing at least the decade when you read this would be tremendously helpful to identify it.

Comment: It was black and white and I would say 1 year or two

Comment: Also the lizard king was using magic to transform he was fat before the transformation

Comment: @LogicDictates the mc minipulated all the children to get what he wants by saying he would boost their powers except a girl lizard woman

Answer (score 2):

*[Game of Familia: Kazoku Senki](https://game-of-familia.fandom.com/wiki/Game_of_Familia:_Kazoku_Senki_Wiki)* by Mikoto Yamaguchi (Mature). I found it after searching for `fat lizard king`.

> The protagonist along with his stepmother and her two younger sisters are summoned into another world where demi-humans are the saviors, but its not to fight against a demon lord, its to fight an Undead Apocalypse monsters called "Dead Mell" that have overrun the world and that can only be killed by using weapons made with holy silver.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 OP is clearly not a native english speaker. He meant that 'fat lizard king'  were his search terms, because that's a physical description of one of the characters in the story.